# Eigenvalues for a block matrix with Toeplitz tridiagonal sub-matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

> Given a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{(2N, 2N)}$ for some $N \in \mathbb{Z}, N > 2$
>
> $$M = \begin{pmatrix}\textbf{0}&I\\A&\textbf{0}\end{pmatrix},$$
>
> where $\textbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{(N, N)}$ is a zeroed matrix, $I \in \mathbb{R}^{(N, N)}$ is the identity matrix and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(N, N)}$ is a negative-definite Toeplitz Tridiagonal matrix with entries: $-2$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the subdiagonal and superdiagonal, i.e.
>
> $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
> &-2 &1 &0 &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &0 \\ 
> &1 &-2 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
> &0 &1 &-2 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
> &\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
> &\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &1 &-2 &1 &0 \\
> &\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &1 &-2 &1 \\
> &0 & \ldots &\ldots &\ldots &0 &1 &-2
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Show that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are imaginary.

Comment: Have you tried computing the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Hint: split the eigenvectors $\nu$ of $M$ into $[u,v]^T$ and write down the eigenvalue equations in terms of $u$ and $v$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{-2+2\cos(\theta_j)}, \quad \theta_j=j\pi/(N+1), \quad  j=1,\ldots,N$.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it using the fact that the block matrices commute, which gives $\det(M - \lambda I) = \det(\lambda^2 I - A I) $ and the fact that this is the determinant of a Toeplitz Tridiagonal matrix to solve this question.